# Do I specify exception types in just the function header or declarations as well? (C++)

Tags: c++, exception, throw

```
  SVector.H:

  void pop_back() throw (underflow_error);
```

In my SVector.cpp file, should I also include the throw (underflow_error) part as well?

```
void pop_back() throw (underflow_error)
{
    // implementation
}
```

OR

```
void pop_back()
{
    // implementation
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I hate throw() statements.  You might be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88573/should-i-use-an-exception-specifier-in-c

Comment: You might be interested in this article by Herb Sutter (http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm):  Moral #1: Never write an exception specification.  Moral #2: Except possibly an empty one, but if I were you I’d avoid even that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`15.4/2`:

> If any declaration of a function has an exception-specification, all declarations, including the definition and an explicit specialization, of that function shall have an exception-specification with the same set of type-ids.