# C++ Syntax question regarding constructor's member initialisation list and throw

Tags: c++

How do I write a ctor definition which has both throw and a member initialisation list? 
Is this correct?

```
ClassName::ClassName(int parameter): datamember_(parameter) throw(ExceptionType)
```

Comment: Please retag your question with the programming language you are using.

Comment: Why don't you look up such trivial stuff in your language reference manual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `throw` thing is part of the function declarator, therefore it should appear before the initialization list (the `:`).

```
ClassName::ClassName(int parameter) throw(ExceptionType) : datamember_(parameter) {
```

BTW, exception specification is [deprecated](http://herbsutter.com/2010/03/13/trip-report-march-2010-iso-c-standards-meeting/) in C++0x, and except `throw()` it is generally useless. See [*Should I use an exception specifier in C++?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88573/should-i-use-an-exception-specifier-in-c).

Comment: If throw is part of the function signature, does it mean that the following (declarations) are valid overloads (given that the above function exists): 
ClassName(int parameter) const throw(ExceptionType);
ClassName(int parameter) throw(ExceptionType2);
ClassName(int parameter) const throw(ExceptionType2);

Comment: @The It's not part of the signature as regards overloading, so no, you can't.