# C++ -- What is the meaning of this statement?

Tags: c++

I saw the following class definition and cannot figure out the meaning of the line 1.

```
class Noisy {
public:
  Noisy() throw();
 ~Noisy() throw();
  Noisy& operator= (const Noisy&) throw();
  Noisy            (const Noisy&) throw(); // Line 1
};
```

What is the meaning of this line and what is the usage of this line?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't a statement.  It is a declaration of a copy constructor that is specified as throwing no exceptions.

You can find out more in [your favorite good introductory C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Sorry for this silly question. I should know that line if it was written as Noisy(const Noisy&) throw() -- Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look at this thread. It will give you some more insight.
[Should I use an exception specifier in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88573/should-i-use-an-exception-specifier-in-c)