# C++ exception definition

Tags: c++, exception

Could anyone explain to me this definition of standard exception in C++:

```
virtual const char* what() const throw();
```

What does `const throw()` mean at the end?

Comment: Why so angry? If you get upset every time you don't know some part of C++, you'll have a heart attack in no time! Also note that exception specifiers are now deprecated, so with luck you'll see fewer and fewer of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are separate issues.

---

## Regarding `const`

From the standard (if too long, only read the **bold** parts):

> #### Nonstatic member functions
>
> [...] A non-static member function may be declared const, volatile, or const volatile. These cv-qualifiers
>   affect the type of the this pointer (9.3.2). They also affect the function type (8.3.5) of the member function;
>   **a member function declared const is a const member function**, a member function declared volatile is
>   a volatile member function and a member function declared const volatile is a const volatile member
>   function. [...]
>
> #### The `this` pointer
>
> [...] In a const member function, the object for which the function is called is accessed through a const access
>   path; therefore, **a const member function shall not modify the object and its non-static data members.** [...]
>
> #### Storage class specifiers
>
> [...] The mutable specifier on a class data member nullifies a const specifier applied to the containing class object
>   and permits modification of the mutable class member even though the rest of the object is const (7.1.6.1).

Summary: A member function qualified with `const` is not allowed to change any member that is not declared `mutable`. The reason for `mutable` is that even if an object is `const`, mechanism like caching can be done; it is good practice that the observable behavior of an object does not change by calling const member function.

---

## Regarding `throw()`

> #### Exception specifications [expect.spec]
>
> A function declaration lists exceptions that its function might directly or indirectly throw by using an
>   exception-specification as a suffix of its declarator.

More specifically, it is a dynamic-exception-specification, and a

> [...] function is said to allow an exception of type E if its dynamic-exception-specification contains a type T for
>   which a handler of type T would be a match (15.3) for an exception of type E.

In other words, the types within `(` and `)` are the exceptions that this function might throw. However, it is common practice to not use non-empty dynamic exception specifications [for some good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88573/should-i-use-an-exception-specifier-in-c).

Using `throw()`, i.e. an empty exception list, in pre-C++11 was accepted practice to annotate functions that never throw. However, as of C++11, the current standard, one should use `noexcept` instead.

Also, as of C++11,

> [ Note: The use of dynamic-exception-specifications is deprecated (see Annex D). —end note ]

so use `noexcept` instead.

Answer (score 9):

These are two separate, unrelated, things.

The `const` means that the member function won't modify any (non-`mutable`) member variables; this in turn means that it can be called on `const` objects. e.g.:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void a() const {
        x = 5;  // Compiler error!
    }

    void b() {
        x = 5;  // This is fine
    }

private:
    int x;
};

int main() {
    Foo       p;
    const Foo q;

    p.a();   // This is fine
    p.b();   // This is fine
    q.a();   // This is fine
    q.b();   // Compiler error!
}
```

The `throw()` is an *exception specifier*.  It declares that this function will not throw an exception.  See e.g. [Should I use an exception specifier in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88573/should-i-use-an-exception-specifier-in-c) for a discussion.

Answer (score 6):

The `const` means that the function will not change any members of the class it is embedded in, `throw()` is an exception specification; the function promises not to throw an exception.

Note that since C++11 the exception specification `throw` is deprecated because of several reasons: exception lists were too hard to maintain while `throw(...)` was to non-expressive, so that `throw()` was basically the only specification used anyway, and these specification were dynamically checked at runtime, producing a large overhead and thus slowing down your application.

Now, you can safely replace `throw()` with `noexcept(true)`, or just `noexcept`. There will be no checks whether such a method actually throws an exception - it's a guarantee you give to the compiler, not vice versa. If an exception is thrown, `std::terminate` is called.