# What is the difference between C++03 `throw()` specifier and C++11 `noexcept`?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, throw, noexcept

Is there any difference between `throw()` and `noexcept` other than being checked at runtime and compile time respectively?

[This Wikipedia C++11 article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Features_removed_or_deprecated) suggests that the C++03 throw specifiers are deprecated.
Why so ... Is the `noexcept` capable enough to cover all that at compile time?

---

Note: I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88573/should-i-use-an-exception-specifier-in-c) and [this article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm), but couldn't determine the solid reason for its deprecation.

Comment: Accodring to this [nice article](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/using-noexcept/) also `noexcept` may incur runtime checks. The main difference between them being that breaking `noexcept` causes `std::terminate` while breaking `throw` causes `std::unexpected`. Also a slightly different stack unwinding behaviour in these cases.

Comment: There is nothing "compile time" checked with some exception specifications that is "runtime" checked on others. It's just a myth created by opponents of C++ exception specifications.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Exception specifiers were deprecated because [exception specifiers are generally a terrible idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/88905/734069). `noexcept` was added because it's the one reasonably useful use of an exception specifier: knowing when a function *won't* throw an exception. Thus it becomes a binary choice: functions that will throw and functions that won't throw.

`noexcept` was added rather than just removing all throw specifiers other than `throw()` because `noexcept` is more powerful. `noexcept` can have a parameter which compile-time resolves into a boolean. If the boolean is true, then the `noexcept` sticks. If the boolean is false, then the `noexcept` doesn't stick and the function may throw.

Thus, you can do something like this:

```
struct<typename T>
{
  void CreateOtherClass() { T t{}; }
};
```

Does `CreateOtherClass` throw exceptions? It might, if `T`'s default constructor can. How do we tell? Like this:

```
struct<typename T>
{
  void CreateOtherClass() noexcept(is_nothrow_default_constructible<T>::value) { T t{}; }
};
```

Thus, `CreateOtherClass()` will throw iff the given type's default constructor throws. This fixes one of the major problems with exception specifiers: their inability to propagate up the call stack.

You can't do this with `throw()`.

Comment: +1 Useful answer, for me anyway. Still searching for an answer that says why I would want to use `noexcept`. I never used `throw()` specifier, ever and am attempting to determine if `noexcept` actually provides any benefit (other than compiler checked documentation).

Comment: Just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787766/when-should-i-really-use-noexcept ...

Comment: @hmjd: "*Still searching for an answer that says why I would want to use noexcept.*" You won't find an answer to that here because that's *not the question* that was asked.

Comment: Yep, I know that. Was just researching `noexcept` and reading a few questions/answers on it. The most important reason I found was that some (possibly all) of the STL containers will not use the move constructor if it is not declared as `noexcept`, which I didn't realise.

Comment: I wonder what happened to the case, that destructors shall not call functions that throw exceptions.

Comment: @Alex: It's fine for destructors to call throwing functions. They just can't allow those exceptions to *escape* the destructor call.

Comment: @NicolBolas agree. but if noexcept would be a guarantee, the compiler could check whether a function may throw or not in a destructor. Thus being able to warn a programmer that a function is noexcept or not.

Comment: @Alex: `noexcept` *is* a guarantee. If an exception tries to leave *any* function that is `noexcept`, then `std::terminate` will be called.

Comment: @NicolBolas the runtime calls `std::terminate`. which is *WAY WORSE*! code can sneak into releases that have functions marked `noexcept`  and at runtime (meaning at customer sites) violations are detected. I meant the compiler guarantees to generate code that doesn't *throw* exceptions in the first place.

Comment: @Alex: C++ is not a *safe* language. It is always the responsibility of the programmer to ensure the integrity of a C++ program. The same goes here: you are allowed to call functions that aren't marked `noexcept`. The language trusts that you will either call these functions in such a way that they will not throw, or that you will call these function in such a way that you will *catch* any exceptions they throw. There is *no reason* to force C++ programmers to only restrict themselves to functions explicitly labeled `noexcept`. That would break *tons* of code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36258/discussion-between-alex-and-nicol-bolas)

Comment: @NicolBolas: One other difference worth noting. If a function is marked `throws()` then if an exception is thrown the stack **must** be unwound upto the scope of that function (so all automatic variables in the function are destroyed) at which point `terminate()` is called (via `unexpected()`). If a function is marked `noexcept` then if an exception is thrown then terminate is called (the unwinding of the stack is implementation defined detail).

Comment: @MartinYork A difference in semantics that is irrelevant to the calling code.

Comment: @hmjd "_The most important reason I found was that some (possibly all) of the STL containers will not use the move constructor if it is not declared as noexcept_" Yes and changing the function decoration from `throw()` to `noexcept` was not needed to do that.

Comment: "_Exception specifiers were deprecated because exception specifiers are generally a terrible idea._" Then the new style is equally "terrible" as the exact same critics apply, except the less useful "throw some exceptions" have been removed (which was never part of the central argument against old style spec)

Comment: @curiousguy: You know, there were several sentences after the first one. Indeed, the very next sentence addresses this exact point. It's almost like I was going somewhere with that. Hence the use of qualifiers like "generally" and so forth.

Comment: @NicolBolas They were found to be of little use, but their bad reputation is similar to the bad rep of MI in many languages, it's based on completely irrelevant or bogus claims, bad example, bad understanding... Bad understanding is fixed by better explanations, not changing language syntax and semantics. I'm *not* saying that the full power of old throw spec was worth keeping given the (relatively extremely small) additional language and impl complexity they caused, but denigration of a tool is bad and awful when it propages deep misunderstanding of programming.

Answer (score 35):

`noexcept` isn't checked at compile time.

> An implementation shall not reject an expression merely because when executed it throws or might throw an exception that the containing function does not allow.

When a function that is declared `noexcept` or `throw()` attempts to throw an exception the only difference is that one calls `terminate` and the othe calls `unexpected` and the latter style of exception handling has effectively been deprecated.

Comment: But if a virtual function has `throw()`/`noexcept`, compile time checking ensure that an overrider also has.

Answer (score 2):

`std::unexpected()` is called by the C++ runtime when a dynamic exception specification is violated: an exception is thrown from a function whose exception specification forbids exceptions of this type.

`std::unexpected()` may also be called directly from the program.

In either case, `std::unexpected` calls the currently installed `std::unexpected_handler`. The default `std::unexpected_handler` calls `std::terminate`.