# Does adding parentheses around a throw argument have any effect?

Tags: c++, throw, parentheses

Is there a difference in writing:

```
throw SomeException;
```

and

```
throw(SomeException);
```

I have seen some sources that claim the latter (with parentheses) is not a good option for some reason but alas I can not recall where I've seen this.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing it with throw specifiers?

Comment: I think it works just like the `return` statement; mechanics are similar, after all.

Comment: I don't know it for `throw`, but for `case` it doesn't matter if you but braces or not, however, some people say it doesn't look nice (+ some coding guideline forbids it). I think it's the same here.

Comment: No I don't think so. Same question applies to `return` by the way. I have seen somewhere it is bad practice to write `return (4);`

Comment: @leemes It may matter in `case` when macros are used; so only in pretty ancient code.

Comment: @Ivaylo It may seem that it's a function call (which it of course isn't)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz yes, I thought of that, but I wondered is there any effect other than confusing the reader

Comment: throw is a statement, not a function call. i would leave the parens out to reflect that unless they are really necessary.

Comment: @Ivaylo `6.6.3` doesn't say anything about it, actually, so I guess normal parentheses are in action.

Comment: The operand of throw is syntactically similar to the operand of a return statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should **not** be any functionality difference between the two expressions apart from the parentheses. I have never heard of any clear reason that says why one should be superior to the other.

To me the first option looks more intuitive as it does not include the unnecessary parentheses!

Also as @Pubby said in the comment, one should not confuse with the throw specifier which requires parentheses (`throw` specifier is *probably* [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833241/difference-between-c03-throw-specifier-c11-noexcept)).