# Difference between "throw(e)" and "throw e"?

Tags: java, exception, throw

I came across this rethrown exception and am surprised that it even compiles.

```
} catch(SomeException e) {
    ...
    throw(e);
}
```

Is there any difference between this throw() and what is normally used?...

```
} catch(SomeException e) {
    ...
    throw e;
}
```

Any links to where this is documented or guidance on choosing one over the other?

Comment: They are the same

Comment: Looks like it's just superfluous grouping parentheses.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't log and throw. If you catch it somewhere else and log it there too, you'll get the mistaken impression there were two exceptions.

Comment: There is  a similar c++ question and the answer says no difference, https://stackoverflow.com/q/14321163

Comment: @AndyTurner depends. It's common that you want to log a problem somewhere where there is more context to the problem, but throw since you don't want to stop exception from propagating.

Comment: @eis In that case the context should be recorded in the exception itself. And while we're at it, logging `e.getMessage()` is a bad idea whether you rethrow or not.

Comment: I removed the log() line so as not to cloud the issue of the question.

Comment: ..and when logging, you usually want the stack trace of the exception to be logged as well (`myLogger.error(e.getMessage(), e)`). `e.getMessage` often doesn't give enough information.

Comment: @biziclop again, depends. It might be information that you do *not* want to expose to end user (where the exception might end up), but it is useful diagnostic in the logs. However I do agree that logging e.getMessage() is almost always wrong thing to do.

Comment: Basically `throw` accepts any expression that evaluates to an instance of `Throwable`. So you could even do `throw constructMyException();` if you've got a method `Exception constructMyException() {...}`. You can even do `throw null;`, but that's particularly naughty.  And of course `(e)` is a valid expression and evaluates to ... well, `e`.

Comment: `(they are)` same as `they are`

Comment: @eis you're talking about logging information that's not in the exception. I'm not objecting to that, I'm talking about not logging the exception and then throwing *the same* exception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quite a few languages allow as many parenthesis around expressions as you want. Java is one of them. The following is perfectly valid code.

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    throw ((((new RuntimeException()))));
  }
}
```

So there's absolutely no difference, except that your source file is two bytes larger.

Comment: "So there's absolutely no difference, except that your source file is two bytes larger." And much less readable.

Answer (score 6):

Functionally they are equivalent.

However, don't choose `throw(e);`, as someone might mistake it for a method call, and the very least will make someone unnecessarily wonder what it is that you're doing. Prefer the normal `throw e;` syntax for clarity.

Comment: Right. Unnecessary parenthesis that are neither functionally required nor a readability improvement are error prone and dead code.

Answer (score 0):

Throw is an instruction to throw a "throwable" (usually an exception)

Think if it like a return statement

```
Public int get value() {
    return 3;
}
```

Is equlivilant of

```
Public int get value() {
    return (3);
}
```

It's the same with throwable.

In face they will complied to the exactly same thing.