# Is there any difference between noexcept and empty throw specification for an lambda expression?

Tags: c++, lambda, noexcept

Given an example:

```
double values[] {2.5, -3.5, 4.5, -5.5, 6.5, -7.5};
std::vector<double> squares(std::end(values) - std::begin(values));

std::transform(std::begin(values), std::end(values), std::begin(values), std::begin(squares),
    [](double x1, double x2) throw() { return x1 * x2; });
```

1. Is this functionally equivalent to the following?

   ```
   [](double x1, double x2) noexcept { return x1 * x2; })
   ```
2. Is there a convincible reason, why should I mark such expression (or similar basic expresions) with either modifiers or in this case, it is better to leave it and simply don't bother?

Comment: Due to gold badge, it will be closed immediately. So just asking others & OP to check if it's a possible duplicate of [Difference between C++03 throw() specifier C++11 noexcept](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12833241/514235)?

Comment: @iammilind: I see from answers, that there is nothing specific to lambda expressions, thus I think it can be treated as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any difference between noexcept and empty throw specification...?

Yes there is.

The first difference that comes to mind is what happens if an exception is thrown?

- In the case of `throw()`, [`std::unexpected()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected) is called. The default handler for `unexpected` will call `terminate`.
- In the case of `noexcept`, [`std::terminate()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) is called.

The second is that the dynamic exception specification is [deprecated](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec#Deprecates).

> **Deprecates**
>
> **`noexcept`** is an improved version of `throw()`, which is deprecated in C++11. Unlike `throw()`, **`noexcept`** will not call `std::unexpected` and may or may not unwind the stack, which potentially allows the compiler to implement **`noexcept`** without the runtime overhead of `throw()`.

---

> Is there a convincible reason, why should I mark such expression (or similar basic expresions) with either modifiers...?

It is an expression of intent. If you intend that the lambda never throws, and if it does it is deemed fatal to the execution of the program, then yes - you should mark the lambda as `noexcept` (`throw()` is deprecated).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they both could be used for declaring functions (including lambdas) which don't throw any exceptions, but [dynamic exception specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) has been deprecated in C++11. And [noexcept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec#Deprecates) (same as `noexcept(true)`) and `throw()` are not exactly the same:

> `noexcept` is an improved version of `throw()`, which is deprecated in C++11. Unlike `throw()`, `noexcept` will not call `std::unexpected` and may or may not unwind the stack, which potentially allows the compiler to implement `noexcept` without the runtime overhead of `throw()`.