# what does what() const throw mean?

Tags: c++, c++11

In *C++ concurrency in Action* page 45 I have this code

```
#include <exception>
#include <memory>

struct empty_stack: std::exception
{
   const char* what() const throw();  //<--- what does this mean?
}
```

Can anyone tell me what does this mean?

this `empty_stack` exception is being thrown by another function if a stack is empty, such as

`if(data.empty()) throw empty_stack();`

but what does the line inside mean?

EDIT:

Someone posted (but was removed! wonder why) this [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) Thanks!

Comment: [Throws nothing = doesn't throw = `noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec).

Comment: It declares the method [`what()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) that returns the exception description. Do you mean the entire line or some particular part of it?

Comment: The entire line. So `what` is just a name for a method? (ergo could be anything?)

Comment: @KansaiRobot `std::exception` provides a virtual method `what`, so no, you must use this specific name to override it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks! Someone posted a link (and deleted) about this.

Comment: @Evg -- `throw()` is not quite the same as `noexcept`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433371/is-there-any-difference-between-noexcept-and-empty-throw-specification-for-an-la). The difference is that if the function throws an exception, if it's marked `throw()` you'll get a call to `std::unexpected()`; if it's marked `noexcept` you'll get a call to `std::terminate()`. `std::unexpected()` by default calls `std::terminate()`, but it's replaceable, so you aren't bound to terminate.

Comment: @PeteBecker, thanks for the link! cppreference says that since C++17 `throw() = noexcept`. Before C++17, stack unwinding is guaranteed.

Comment: @Evg -- hmm, it's more subtle than I thought. I haven't been paying attention lately...

Answer (score 3):

```
 const char* what() const throw();
 |-> return type
             |-> name of the method
                 |-> parameter
                    |-> it is a const method
                          |-> exception specification
```

It is a `const` method called `what` that takes no parameters, returns a `const char *` and is specified to not throw an exception.

Note the [dynamic exception specifications](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) are deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17/20. For what it does I quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec#Explanation):

> If the function throws an exception of the type not listed in its exception specification, the function `std::unexpected` is called. The default function calls `std::terminate`, but it may be replaced by a user-provided function (via `std::set_unexpected`) which may call `std::terminate` or throw an exception. If the exception thrown from `std::unexpected` is accepted by the exception specification, stack unwinding continues as usual. If it isn't, but `std::bad_exception` is allowed by the exception specification, `std::bad_exception` is thrown. Otherwise, `std::terminate` is called.