# Was there any version of C++ (even pre-standard) were `throw()` did not mean "cannot throw, ever"?

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer, noexcept, exception-specification

The questions is about history of C++: ISO standards, revised standards (with DR), even draft standards; all count as "a C++".

Is there any C++ where this property does *not* hold:

**A function declared with an empty throw-specification `throw()` cannot throw an exception.**

I'd like a counter example if that property does not hold.

Comments:

It goes without saying that throwing, then catching (without rethrowing) an exception *inside* a function, does that turn it info "a function throwing an exception". A function throwing an exception, according to its specification, throws at its caller. (If you do stuff internally it isn't part of the specification by definition.)

[Let's say that `longjmp` is forbidden as we have destructible objects.]

Others equivalent expressions of that question are:

Was there ever any case where the caller of a declared no-throw function had to worry about the possibility (equivalent properties):

- of that function giving back control to its caller but not with a return statement
- of seeing (and being able to catch) an exception thrown by that function
- of having stack unwinding caused by the call of that function
- of the caller not being non throwing if all other actions (other than calling that function) are non throwing

In other words, was there any C++ **where the compiler could not *optimize the calling function* based on seeing a no-throw declaration of a called function**?

Comment: The history of various exception related function annotations is long and sordid. I believe that you are correct. But it's hard to know for sure. I am pretty sure that using `throw()` specifications in C++17 is illegal. They were deprecated.

Comment: @Omnifarious If throw spec were deprecated and then removed, it's useful to understand why, esp. for other PL designers.

Comment: "*was there any C++ where the compiler could not optimize the calling function based on seeing a no-throw declaration of a called function?*" This is *not* the same question as the one your title asks. This requires knowing what you mean by "optimize the calling function". *Compiler* optimizations about non-throwing are primarily around optimizing the throwee, not the thrower.

Comment: @NicolBolas If a compiler doesn't have "zero overhead exception handling", knowing that a non inline function cannot throw might be the last thing needed to see that nothing in a block can throw, so it might makes a big difference. Hopefully these compilers that implement exceptions like return codes are rare now.

Answer (score 3):

C++17 has deprecated `throw` as a function annotation, mostly. It still allows `throw()` and considers it equivalent to `noexcept(true)`. That means that `throw()` is an indication that a function is not supposed to exit because of an exception. And violating the `noexcept(true)` guarantee results in undefined behavior.

The semantics of `throw()` before C++17 were distinct and different. It used to be promised that a call to `::std::unexpected()` would happen if the `throw()` clause was violated (i.e. an exception was thrown and resulted in the function exiting).

So, that means that before C++17 a compiler still needed to have some mechanism for detecting that a function did not exit from an exception, even if it was annotated with `throw()`. This is one of the reasons that the `throw(...)` function annotation (with stuff between the parenthesis) was deprecated because it would make no sense to have `throw()` to change to be equivalent to `noexcept(true)` without removing the other uses that the `throw` annotation had.

This code in compiler explorer [demonstrates the 'unexpected exception' handler](https://godbolt.org/z/LMQj2G). If you change the standard requested to C++17, you'll see the code for that go away.

```
extern void a_different_function();

void test_function() throw ()
{
    a_different_function();
}
```

Comment: On one hand under `-std=c++11` a call will execute `test_function():
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    a_different_function()
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
` on the other hand w/ `-std=c++17` the exact same code will executed.

Comment: @curiousguy - But lots of extra code gets generated for -std=c++17. One way of implementing an exception return could be modifying the return value on the stack before returning. Here is a slight modification: https://godbolt.org/z/vGtGQV - as you can see, it no longer attempts to call the unexpected handler in c++17. Technically, I believe it could just assume that `should_throw` is always `false`, though it doesn't do that now. It's clear that C++17 has a very different attitude about a promise not to throw an exception than C++11.

Comment: @curiousguy - I'm sort of wrong. If a `noexcept` function throws, the behavior is not undefined. It is specified that `::std::terminate` is called. So, the kinds of optimizations the compiler can do are very limited. I wish they had simply said it was undefined behavior. - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec

Comment: @Omnifarious: Note that the code needed to terminate is less complex than the code needed to implement the `throw()` behavior (which explicitly requires unwinding the stack to that point). It's not necessarily zero obviously, but it is less.

Answer (score 1):

> In other words, was there any C++ where the compiler could not optimize the calling function based on seeing a no-throw declaration of a called function?

The answer to this direct question is no. But that alone is highly misleading.

A compiler's ability to do any kind of optimization on a a function which happens to call some other function that has a `throw()` declaration is extremely limited. The only real thing a compiler could do is eliminate the emission of any code dealing with exceptions in a caller function. But because of the nature of said code, it would really only be applicable if every function it calls does not throw. That's pretty much it as far as compiler optimizations of a function that calls a `throw()` function is concerned.

People often talk today about how `noexcept` enables optimizations. And that is true; judicious use of `noexcept` can cause code that operates on such functions to become more efficient. But it is important to remember that using `noexcept` does not enable compiler optimizations; it enables *user-code* optimizations.

Let's take the classic case of `vector<T>` for a `T` with `noexcept` move support. That case is not faster because the compiler sees what would otherwise be a series of copies and automatically changes them to moves just because the move constructor is `noexcept`. That isn't even possible for a compiler to do; it isn't allowed to rearrange your code like that, since this would be a *detectable* change depending on what your copy/move constructors do.

Such cases get faster because the source-code implementation of `vector` detects that `T` is nothrow-moveable. Having detected that case, it will then invoke a completely different codepath for shuffling elements of the `vector` around. The code calling the non-throwing function became faster because the calling code optimized *itself*, not because the *compiler* detected anything.

To put it simply, compiler optimization of the calling function was never really the point of `throw()` declarations.

Comment: "_`noexcept` enables optimizations_" Right, the **operator** `noexcept(some code)` does, combined w/ the exception specification (explicit or deduced for implicitly declared functions). But then the old so called "dynamic" exception specification `throw()` provides the same user optimization benefit as the (non "dynamic"?) `noexcept` exception specification.

Comment: @curiousguy: I'm not really sure I understand your point. The `noexcept` exception specification was added to repair a deficiency in the behavior of the `throw()` specification. I know you know that because [you asked a question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58576026/734069) which was answered with exactly that point. Here, you're asking about optimizations of the *caller* of the non-throwing function, which is a different conversation from why `throw()` needed to be ditched.

Comment: The point is simply that as a contract w/ the caller, the old throw spec worked. Many ppl claimed it did not really.

Comment: @curiousguy: As a means to pass untyped objects around, `void*` works too. That doesn't make it a good idea, nor does it mean that there aren't better ways of achieving the same effect. So outside of disproving the claims of these mythical "many ppl," (I personally have never heard anyone say that dynamic exception specifications don't establish a contract. The primary argument against them is that the contract they establish is largely not a thing which should be established), what is the point? `throw()` still needed to be replaced, even if not for this reason.

Comment: The contract that a called function cannot exit with an exception is not a useful contract? Is it not what the `noexcept` operator tests?

Comment: "_So outside of disproving the claims of these mythical "many ppl," (I personally have never heard anyone say that dynamic exception specifications don't establish a contract_" Pretty much everyone on SO except me quote "_A Pragmatic Look at Exception Specifications_" by Herb Sutter as a reliable source, so yes many ppl don't believe there is a contract that: "- Guarantee that functions will only throw listed exceptions (possibly none).
- Enable compiler optimizations based on the knowledge that only listed exceptions (possibly none) will be thrown." I hurts to read that.

Comment: @curiousguy: But compiler optimizations aren't enabled based on exception specifications. This very answer makes it perfectly clear that optimizations based on `noexcept` expressions are not "compiler optimizations"; they're code optimizations. Calling them compiler optimizations is like calling the use of quicksort rather than bubble sort a "compiler optimizations".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202117/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-nicol-bolas).