# How to prompt programmers to use try except clause in python?

Tags: python, exception, static-analysis, pylint, try-except

Let's say I have a methodA that raises an exception:

```
def methodA(x, y):
     if y != 0: 
         z = x / y
         return z
     else:
         raise ZeroDivisionError("zero can not be a denominator")
```

And in methodB I called methodA without handling the exception:

```
def methodB(x, y):
     print methodA(x, y)
```

Here I want something that could warn me there is a potential risk of `ZeroDivisionError` in methodB, and that it's better to catch it. 
Is there any way to add some certain codes in methodA, or can we use some tool to find that I ignored some important exceptions?

Comment: I doubt it - how would the static analysis know whether you deliberately are letting the exception percolate up to somewhere more sensible to catch it (which may not be in your code at all, remember!) or have just forgotten to deal with it? It's helpful for the documentation for `methodA` to note that it can `raise ZeroDivisionError`, but otherwise it's up to the consumer to handle as they see fit.

Comment: Or, a third option, whether you've *already dealt with it*, e.g. by checking `y > 0` in `methodB` (or wherever it's called from)?

Comment: Nitpick: `y` is the denominator here, but the exception refers to it as the numerator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything close to such a mechanism in Python, but in general `methodA` should not care about if `methodB` deals with the exception or not. At each level (such as `methodB`) only exceptions that `methodB` could deal with (at some documented/specified level) should be caught. If `methodB` can not deal with for example `ZeroDivisionError` then perhaps nobody can (and then not catching it is the correct hing to do), or, it could be that in some call graph, `methodC` will catch it and do what is correct in context of `methodC`.

Also note the somewhat related (but reverse) question for Java: [Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation)

and for C++ https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114338/why-are-exception-specifications-bad and [Should I use an exception specifier in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88573/should-i-use-an-exception-specifier-in-c)

Comment: "in general `methodA` should not care about if `methodB` deals with the exception or not"  --- I'd go one step further:  By raising an exception, `methodA` is _explicitly_ stating that it can not or will not deal with the situation.  Not only does `methodA` not care if the exception is ever handled, it has completely given up on the whole program, and is intentionally crashing it.

Comment: "it has completely given up on the whole program, and is intentionally crashing it". No, that is not true at all. If it had given up on the whole program it would not need to be exception safe. Exception safe code use exceptions to tell that it could not do its part. Exceptions are in such case always *possibly recoverable*, completely depending on the callers.

Comment: Exceptions _always_ crash the program.  Even a comparatively innocent `StopIteration` will crash a Python program if it's not caught and handled.  The only... er... exception is when some other code higher up the call stack (which presumably knows better) dives to the rescue.  Since the exception-raising code _can not know_ if a given exception will or will not be caught, a `raise` command must always be considered intentionally crashing the program, since that's the most likely outcome.  If the program somehow survives, that is a (hopefully pleasant) surprise.

Comment: Again I don't agree but let's leave this.

Comment: Agreed --- this is is a tangent.