# multiple exception throwing in c++98

Tags: c++, syntax, c++98

I'm new to c++, **using c++98**

I'm trying to throw from the same function more than one exception and i'm struggling with the syntax - which made me wonder if that's even possible without a workaround...

The function should look like this:

```
Worker* CreateWorker(myIO* workerInfo) throw (AgeNotInRange), throw(WorkerTypeNotDefined);
```

I've tried also without the comma with no success...

Comment: What does your book say?

Comment: I suppose you mean I'm learning from library book or something like that. This is not the situation, i'm learning without any official book, from some presentations with missing information...

Comment: You should change that.

Comment: You'd be much better off not to use throw specifiers . They just pollute your code and make it behave worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's:

```
Worker* CreateWorker(myIO* workerInfo) throw(AgeNotInRange, WorkerTypeNotDefined);
```

But, really, [avoid exception specifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/88905/560648).